# How to make download functionality for meme generator in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-processing, canvas, download

[Meme Generater App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHo6A.png)

I have built meme generator app that basically have an image and top text, bottom text over it. User can change top text, bottom text and also change the image.

**How can I add the download functionality so that user can download meme image with text over it?**

My app is written in ReactJS so please tell me the React friendly way.

Comment: This question reads like a request to write code - that's not what stack overflow is

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not requesting to write code. I only want to know the name of methods that can fulfil my task.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, you shoud capture a div content as image. using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

```
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
const exportAsImage = async (el, imageFileName) => {
const canvas = await html2canvas(element);
const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
downloadImage(image, imageFileName);
};
const downloadImage = (blob, fileName) => {
const fakeLink = window.document.createElement("a");
fakeLink.style = "display:none;";
fakeLink.download = fileName;
fakeLink.href = blob;

document.body.appendChild(fakeLink);
fakeLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(fakeLink);

fakeLink.remove();
};

export default exportAsImage;






export default function App() {
const exportRef = useRef();

return (
<>
<div className="parent">
<div ref={exportRef}>
<p>title top</p>
<img src="meme.png"></img>
</div>
</div>
<button onClick={() => exportAsImage(exportRef.current, "test")}>
Capture Image
</button>
</>
)
}
```

ref https://blog.logrocket.com/export-react-components-as-images-html2canvas/

Comment: It is very much helpful, but I am only getting the text not the meme image in downloaded Png file. Any solution for this ?

Comment: Does html2canvas supports images URL came from Api because I am using this?

Comment: Yes, html2canvas capture div content, so if div contains image, some text,... will export picture as you see. If you need more support. Give me your code, i wil help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73762524/reactjs-elements-not-converting-to-canvas-properly-using-html2canvas

Comment: I have added another question with all the code regarding same issue so please help me out.